# Why is my 95% CI from a simulation being either 100% or 0%?

Tags: regression, bayesian, confidence-interval, simulation, jags

So what I intended doing with the code is to simulate dataset with the outcome being number of parasites that died (yi) out of every n=50 parasites on the host. There are 2 treatment groups (control and treat). The beta-binomial is parameterized in terms of rho and p. The rho represents the intraclass correlation given by 1/(1+alpha+beta), the "p" surviving probability varies and follows a beta-distribution, yi represents the outcome. 4 different outcomes are expected to be generated based on the different levels of rho so that I evaluate the influence of rho on the outcome and CI. 100 simulations were done for each scenario. I fitted both binomial and beta-binomial model on data afterwards, however, the coverage of the 95% CI is always either 100% or 0%.  What are the possible causes of this issue, is it normal?

```r
### FUNCTION FOR GENERATING BETA-BINOMIAL DATA

data=function (beta.mu, beta.trt2, rho1, rho2, rho3, rho4, n, N){
    logit <- beta.mu + beta.trt2 * trt2    #logit function to model the log odd
    p= plogis(logit)    #generating probability from the logit model using the inverse logit

#defining model parameters for the beta-distribution 
    alpha1 =  ((1-rho1)*p)/rho1
    beta1 =  (1 - p)*(1-rho1)/rho1
  
    alpha2 =  ((1-rho2)*p)/rho2
    beta2 =  (1 - p)*(1-rho2)/rho2
  
    alpha3 =  ((1-rho3)*p)/rho3
    beta3 =  (1 - p)*(1-rho3)/rho3
  
  alpha4 =  ((1-rho4)*p)/rho4
  beta4 =  (1 - p)*(1-rho4)/rho4
  
#sampling data from the beta-binomial by sampling from the binomial but with a varying probability from the beta distribution
    y1=rbinom(N, n, prob=rbeta(N, alpha1, beta1))
    y2=rbinom(N, n, prob=rbeta(N, alpha1, beta1))
  
    y3=rbinom(N, n, prob=rbeta(N, alpha3, beta3))
    y4=rbinom(N, n, prob=rbeta(N, alpha4, beta4))
  
    dat1=data.frame(n, trt1, trt2, y1, y2, y3, y4)
    return(dat1)
}
```

Below is the simulation and modeling codes

````
######################################################################################

####DEFINING THE BETA-BINOMIAL AND BINOMIAL MODELS IN FOR JUGS IN R#####################

#Parameters for generating the data with surving probability of 0.55 for control group and 0.055 for treatment group resulting in an efficacy of 0.90 (i.e; 1-0.055/0.55)

beta.mu = 0.7256268
beta.trt2 = -3.132089

#PARAMETERS FOR INTRACLASS CORRELATION [RHO= 1/(1+alpha+beta)]
rho1=0.01 
rho2=0.05 
rho3=0.1 
rho4=0.2 
N=16 #Sample size
n=50 #number of parasites per animal
#############################MODEL FOR RHO1######################################################

modelString="model {
 ### Prior distributions
 
    rho1 ~ dunif(0,1)
  beta1.trt2 ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  beta1.mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  
  #likelihood
  
  for (i in 1:N) {
    p[i] ~ dbeta(alpha1[i], beta1[i])
    y1[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    alpha1[i] =  ((1-rho1)*mu[i])/rho1
    beta1[i] =  (1 - mu[i])*(1-rho1)/rho1
    logit(mu[i]) <- beta1.mu + beta1.trt2 * trt2[i] 
    
  }
  
   #using inverse logit to compute probability and Relative risk 
    p1.control <- ilogit(beta1.mu)
    p1.trt2 <- ilogit(beta1.mu + beta1.trt2)
    RR12 <- p1.trt2/p1.control


    ##Computing EFFICACY of treatment
EFFICACY1.Test = 1-RR12
}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='betabinomial1.txt')



###BINOMIAL 
modelString="
model {
 ### Prior distributions
beta1.trt2 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)
mu1 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)


#model
for (i in 1:N) {
    y1[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- mu1 + beta1.trt2 * trt2[i] 
 } 
    
    
        
# Relative risk
    p1.control <- ilogit(mu1)
    p1.trt2 <- ilogit(mu1 + beta1.trt2)
    RR12 <- p1.trt2/p1.control
    
    ##EFFICACY  
EFFICACY1.Test = 1-RR12

}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='binomial1.txt')


###############################MODEL FOR RHO2####################################################

modelString="model {
 ### Prior distributions
 
    rho2 ~ dunif(0,1)
  beta2.trt2 ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  beta2.mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  
  #likelihood
  
  for (i in 1:N) {
    p[i] ~ dbeta(alpha2[i], beta2[i])
    y2[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    alpha2[i] =  ((1-rho2)*mu[i])/rho2
    beta2[i] =  (1 - mu[i])*(1-rho2)/rho2
    logit(mu[i]) <- beta2.mu + beta2.trt2 * trt2[i] 
    
  }
  
   #Relative risk
    p2.control <- ilogit(beta2.mu)
    p2.trt2 <- ilogit(beta2.mu + beta2.trt2)
    RR22 <- p2.trt2/p2.control


    ##EFFICACY
EFFICACY2.Test = 1-RR22
}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='betabinomial2.txt')



###BINOMIAL 
modelString="
model {
 ### Prior distributions
beta2.trt2 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)
mu2 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)


#model
for (i in 1:N) {
    y2[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- mu2 + beta2.trt2 * trt2[i] 
 } 
    
        
        
# Relative risk
    p2.control <- ilogit(mu2)
    p2.trt2 <- ilogit(mu2 + beta2.trt2)
    RR22 <- p2.trt2/p2.control
    
    ##EFFICACY
EFFICACY2.Test = 1-RR22

}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='binomial2.txt')

###################### MODEL FOR RHO3 #########################################


modelString="model {
 ### Prior distributions
 
    rho3 ~ dunif(0,1)
  beta3.trt2 ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  beta3.mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  
  #likelihood
  
  for (i in 1:N) {
    p[i] ~ dbeta(alpha3[i], beta3[i])
    y3[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    alpha3[i] =  ((1-rho3)*mu[i])/rho3
    beta3[i] =  (1 - mu[i])*(1-rho3)/rho3
    logit(mu[i]) <- beta3.mu + beta3.trt2 * trt2[i] 
    
  }
  
   #Relative risk
    p3.control <- ilogit(beta3.mu)
    p3.trt2 <- ilogit(beta3.mu + beta3.trt2)
    RR32 <- p3.trt2/p3.control


    ##EFFICACY
EFFICACY3.Test = 1-RR32
}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='betabinomial3.txt')



###BINOMIAL 
modelString="
model {
 ### Prior distributions
beta3.trt2 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)
mu3 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)


#model
for (i in 1:N) {
    y3[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- mu3 + beta3.trt2 * trt2[i] 
 } 
    
        
        
# Relative risk
    p3.control <- ilogit(mu3)
    p3.trt2 <- ilogit(mu3 + beta3.trt2)
    RR32 <- p3.trt2/p3.control
    
    ##EFFICACY
EFFICACY3.Test = 1-RR32

}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='binomial3.txt')


############################MODELS FOR RHO4#######################################################

modelString="model {
 ### Prior distributions
 
    rho4 ~ dunif(0,1)
  beta4.trt2 ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  beta4.mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001);
  
  #likelihood
  
  for (i in 1:N) {
    p[i] ~ dbeta(alpha4[i], beta4[i])T(0.00001,0.99999)
    y4[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    alpha4[i] =  ((1-rho4)*mu[i])/rho4
    beta4[i] =  (1 - mu[i])*(1-rho4)/rho4
    logit(mu[i]) <- beta4.mu + beta4.trt2 * trt2[i] 
    
  }
  
   #Relative risk
    p4.control <- ilogit(beta4.mu)
    p4.trt2 <- ilogit(beta4.mu + beta4.trt2)
    RR42 <- p4.trt2/p4.control


    ##EFFICACY
EFFICACY4.Test = 1-RR42
}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='betabinomial4.txt')



###BINOMIAL 
modelString="
model {
 ### Prior distributions
beta4.trt2 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)
mu4 ~ dnorm(0.0,0.000001)


#model
for (i in 1:N) {
    y4[i] ~ dbinom(p[i], n[i])
    logit(p[i]) <- mu4 + beta4.trt2 * trt2[i] 
 } 
    
        
        
# Relative risk
    p4.control <- ilogit(mu4)
    p4.trt2 <- ilogit(mu4 + beta4.trt2)
    RR42 <- p4.trt2/p4.control
    
  ##EFFICACY  
EFFICACY4.Test = 1-RR42

}
"
writeLines(modelString, con='binomial4.txt')

#########################################################################
# NUMBER OF TICKS PER ANIMAL
N=16
n=rep(50,N) 

#TREATMENT GROUP 
trt=gl(2,1,N)
trt1 <- ifelse(trt == '1', 1, 0) 
trt2<- ifelse(trt == '2', 1, 0) 

#NUMBER OF REPLICATIONS
repsim=100
par=6

dat=cbind(n,trt1,trt2)
dat=data.frame(dat)

#MATRIX FOR STORING RESULTS OF THE MODEL PER EACH SIMULATION
matrix_betabin1=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)
matrix_bin1=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)

matrix_betabin2=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)
matrix_bin2=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)

matrix_betabin3=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)
matrix_bin3=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)

matrix_betabin4=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)
matrix_bin4=matrix(NA,ncol=par,nrow=repsim)

for(i in 1:repsim){ # Start the loop
  set.seed(48054)
  
  ##DATA CAN BE GENERATED USING THIS SELF-PROGRAMED FUNCTION OR THE rbetabinom function from (VGAM Package)
  dat<-data(beta.mu, beta.trt2,rho1,rho2,rho3,rho4,n,N)
  
  #dat$y1=rbetabinom(N,n,prob=plogis(beta.mu + beta.trt2 * dat$trt2 ),rho=rho1)
  #dat$y2=rbetabinom(N,n,prob=plogis(beta.mu + beta.trt2 * dat$trt2 ),rho=rho2)
  #dat$y3=rbetabinom(N,n,prob=plogis(beta.mu + beta.trt2 * dat$trt2 ),rho=rho3)
  #dat$y4=rbetabinom(N,n,prob=plogis(beta.mu + beta.trt2 * dat$trt2 ),rho=rho4)
  
  #LIST DATASET FOR JAGS
  datjags <- list( N = N, #number of observations (=animals)
                   y1 = dat$y1, #surviving parasites for Rho1
               y2 = dat$y2, #surviving parasites for Rho2
                   y3 = dat$y3, #surviving parasites for Rho3
               y4 = dat$y4, #surviving parasites for Rho4
                   trt2 = dat$trt2, #treatment group
               n = dat$n) #amount of parasites that were introduced per animal
  
  runjags.options(method = "rjags")
  
  #Initialising beta
  set.seed(20091117)
  init1 <- list(beta.trt2 = 0.6,
                beta.mu = -2.3)
  init2 <- list(beta.trt2 = 0.8,
                beta.mu = -3.0)
  init3 <- list(beta.trt2 = 0.3,
                beta.mu = -3.0)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO1
  betabinomial1 <- autorun.jags(model = "betabinomial1.txt",
                                monitor = c("beta1.mu","beta1.trt2","p1.control","p1.trt2","RR12", "EFFICACY1.Test"),
                                data = datjags,
                                inits = list(init1, init2, init3),
                                #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                                thin = 5,
                                n.chains = 3)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO2
  betabinomial2 <- autorun.jags(model = "betabinomial2.txt",
                                monitor = c("beta2.mu","beta2.trt2","p2.control","p2.trt2","RR22", "EFFICACY2.Test"),
                                data = datjags,
                                inits = list(init1, init2, init3),
                                #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                                thin = 5,
                                n.chains = 3)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO3
  betabinomial3 <- autorun.jags(model = "betabinomial3.txt",
                                monitor = c("beta3.mu","beta3.trt2","p3.control","p3.trt2","RR32", "EFFICACY3.Test"),
                                data = datjags,
                                inits = list(init1, init2, init3),
                                #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                                thin = 5,
                                n.chains = 3)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO4
  betabinomial4 <- autorun.jags(model = "betabinomial4.txt",
                                monitor = c("beta4.mu","beta4.trt2","p4.control","p4.trt2","RR42", "EFFICACY4.Test"),
                                data = datjags,
                                inits = list(init1, init2, init3),
                                #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                                thin = 5,
                                n.chains = 3)
  
  
  ##EXTRACTING HPD OF THE BETATBINOMIAL MODELS
  matrix_betabin1[i,1:3]<-betabinomial1$HPD[6,]
  matrix_betabin1[i,4]=matrix_betabin1[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_betabin1[i,5]=matrix_betabin1[i,3]-matrix_betabin1[i,1]
  
  matrix_betabin2[i,1:3]<-betabinomial2$HPD[6,]
  matrix_betabin2[i,4]=matrix_betabin2[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_betabin2[i,5]=matrix_betabin2[i,3]-matrix_betabin2[i,1]
  
  matrix_betabin3[i,1:3]<-betabinomial3$HPD[6,]
  matrix_betabin3[i,4]=matrix_betabin3[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_betabin3[i,5]=matrix_betabin3[i,3]-matrix_betabin3[i,1]
  
  matrix_betabin4[i,1:3]<-betabinomial4$HPD[6,]
  matrix_betabin4[i,4]=matrix_betabin4[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_betabin4[i,5]=matrix_betabin4[i,3]-matrix_betabin4[i,1]
  
  
  #####BINOMIAL MODEL
  runjags.options(method = "rjags")

    #Initialising beta
  set.seed(20091117)
  init1 <- list(beta.trt2 = 0.6,
                beta.mu = -2.3)
  init2 <- list(beta.trt2 = 0.8,
                beta.mu = -3.0)
  init3 <- list(beta.trt2 = 0.3,
                beta.mu = -3.0)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO1
  binomial1 <- autorun.jags(model = "binomial1.txt",
                            monitor = c("mu1","beta1.trt2","p1.control","p1.trt2","RR12", "EFFICACY1.Test"),
                            data = datjags,
                            inits = list(init1, init2, init2),
                            #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                            thin = 5,
                            n.chains = 3)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO2
  binomial2 <- autorun.jags(model = "binomial2.txt",
                            monitor = c("mu2","beta2.trt2","p2.control","p2.trt2","RR22", "EFFICACY2.Test"),
                            data = datjags,
                            inits = list(init1, init2, init2),
                            #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                            thin = 5,
                            n.chains = 3)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO3
  binomial3 <- autorun.jags(model = "binomial3.txt",
                            monitor = c("mu3","beta3.trt2","p3.control","p3.trt2","RR32", "EFFICACY3.Test"),
                            data = datjags,
                            inits = list(init1, init2, init2),
                            #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                            thin = 5,
                            n.chains = 3)
  
  ##MODEL WITH DATA FROM RHO4
  binomial4 <- autorun.jags(model = "binomial4.txt",
                            monitor = c("mu4","beta4.trt2","p4.control","p4.trt2","RR42", "EFFICACY4.Test"),
                            data = datjags,
                            inits = list(init1, init2, init2),
                            #burnin = 1000, sample = 10000, 
                            thin = 5,
                            n.chains = 3)
  
  #EXTRACTING HPD FROM THE BINOMIAL MODEL
  matrix_bin1[i,1:3]<-binomial1$HPD[6,]
  matrix_bin1[i,4]=matrix_bin1[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_bin1[i,5]=matrix_bin1[i,3]-matrix_bin1[i,1]
  
  matrix_bin2[i,1:3]<-binomial2$HPD[6,]
  matrix_bin2[i,4]=matrix_bin2[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_bin2[i,5]=matrix_bin2[i,3]-matrix_bin2[i,1]
  
  matrix_bin3[i,1:3]<-binomial3$HPD[6,]
  matrix_bin3[i,4]=matrix_bin3[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_bin3[i,5]=matrix_bin3[i,3]-matrix_bin3[i,1]
  
  matrix_bin4[i,1:3]<-binomial4$HPD[6,]
  matrix_bin4[i,4]=matrix_bin4[i,2]-0.90
  matrix_bin4[i,5]=matrix_bin4[i,3]-matrix_bin4[i,1]
  
  
  #DETERMINING THE COVERAGE STATUS OF THE 95% HPD OF EACH SIMULATED DATA 
  matrix_betabin1[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_betabin1[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_betabin1[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_bin1[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_bin1[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_bin1[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_betabin2[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_betabin2[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_betabin2[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_bin2[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_bin2[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_bin2[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_betabin3[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_betabin3[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_betabin3[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_bin3[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_bin3[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_bin3[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_betabin4[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_betabin4[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_betabin4[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  matrix_bin4[i,6]=ifelse(matrix_bin4[i,1] < 0.90 & matrix_bin4[i,3] > 0.90, 1, 0) 
  
  
}

#EXTRACTING SUMMRRIES OF THE MODELS
SIM_HPD2<-matrix(, nrow = 8, ncol = 8)
colnames(SIM_HPD2)<-c("Lower95","Median","Upper95","bias","interval","Coverage","Rho","Model")
SIM_HPD2[1,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_betabin1[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin1[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin1[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin1[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin1[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin1[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[2,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_bin1[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin1[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin1[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin1[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin1[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin1[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[3,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_betabin2[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin2[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin2[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin2[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin2[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin2[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[4,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_bin2[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin2[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin2[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin2[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin2[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin2[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[5,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_betabin3[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin3[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin3[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin3[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin3[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin3[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[6,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_bin3[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin3[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin3[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin3[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin3[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin3[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[7,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_betabin4[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin4[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_betabin4[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin4[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin4[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_betabin4[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[8,1:6]<-c(mean( matrix_bin4[,1],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin4[,2],na.rm=T),mean( matrix_bin4[,3],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin4[,4],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin4[,5],na.rm=T),mean(matrix_bin4[,6],na.rm=T))
SIM_HPD2[,7]<-gl(4,2,8)
SIM_HPD2[,8]<-gl(2,1,8)

SIM_HPD2[,8] <- rep(c("Beta-Binomial","Binomial"),4)
SIM_HPD2[,7] <- c("0.01","0.01","0.05","0.05","0.1","0.1","0.2","0.2")

SIM_HPD2

```
````

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It would help if you added comments to your code so we can read what it does and what you intend for it to do.

Comment: @soothe your code is hard to interpret for just a beta-binomial outcome.  Usually, however, if you have your credible intervals at a single point, you have a bad prior distribution.  For example, if you had a Haldane prior and tossed ten heads in a row, your credible interval would be the point 1 (or 0 depending on how you coded heads).  It could also be an algebra error that pushes everything in one direction or the other.  Please comment your code.

Comment: @DaveHarris I have added more details for your information. I hope it helps now

Comment: @soothe Sorry, this is an enormous amount of work to unwind. I do have a couple of suggestions, though. Run real-world data through the non-simulation section first. If you get good intervals, then the error sits in the generation portion and not the prior or the model structure.

If that works out, then move the variances on your normal prior, and make them much larger. You could have created effective zeroes somewhere.

Finally, plot your simulated data. Does it look the way you think it should?